# Which of the following is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following is uncountable?

$1.\{f|f:\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{Z}\}$

$2.\{f|f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}\}$

My attempt:I think first is countable  because we can make a bijection from this to $\mathbb{Z^2}$,am I correct?About second option I do not have any idea.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes on the first. For the second, you can use a 'diagonalising' argument to show the set is uncountable, you could also notice that it is the set of characteristic functions of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, or you could notice that $\phi(f) = \sum_{k \ge 0} f(k) {1 \over 2^{k+1}}$ is a surjective map onto $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for 2:  $\{f\mid f:\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}\}$ has the same cardinality as the power set of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So second is uncountable???

Comment: Yes, because the power set of any set $A$ has cardinality strictly greater than the cardinality of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first is countable, due to the bijection you mentioned.

The second is uncountable, because you can create a bijection from there to the the range $[0, 1)$ represented as binary numbers.